# unicode UTF-8, Decoding issue

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

UTF-8 is variable-length encoding. If a character can be represented using a single byte eg: A (alphabet A in English), UTF-8 will encode it with a single byte. If it requires two bytes, it will use two bytes and so on.
Now consider i encode A (01000001) あ(11100011 10000001 10000010). 
This will be stored in memory as continuous space: 01000001 11100011 10000001 10000010. 
My question is while decoding, how does the editor knows that 1st byte is for first character only and next 3 bytes are for 2nd character?

** It could end up decoding 4 characters where each byte is considered as character, I mean where is the distinction here.

Comment: Have you tried decoding that? Did you end up with 4 characters?

Comment: The encoding is length-prefixed, so you know how long each sequence is. E.g. `1110xxxx` means three bytes (three "one"s).

Comment: @Kerrek SB As per your answer the first three 1's make up the length notation. Consider  (Unicode Scalar Value: U+2070E) whose binary value is 0010 0000 0111 0000 1110, here this does not contain the 4 1's.

Comment: @Anthony McGrath My editor or browser does print out the exact symbol as i stored it but I wanted to theoretically understand How the editor does the decoding.

Comment: @user9185862 UTF-8 does not directly use the binary representation of the Unicode code point. The UTF-8 representation of the character  is `F0 A0 9C 8E`, or `11110000 10100000 10011100 10001110`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 6):

The UTF-8 encoding tells the program how many bytes there are for each encoded codepoint.  Any byte starting with `0xxxxxxx` is an ASCII character from 0 to 127.  Any byte starting with `10xxxxxx` is a continuation byte and can only occur after a starting byte: `110xxxxx`, `1110xxxx` or `11110xxx` specify that the next byte, two bytes or three bytes are continuation bytes, respectively.

If there aren’t the right number of continuation bytes, or a continuation byte ever appears in the wrong place, then the string is not valid UTF-8.  Some programs take advantage of this to try to auto-detect the encoding.

Comment: i checked it with available examples and your claim matches them, thank you.